# Cannot POST /register

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am building my first node.js app, and I am starting with the authentication. So far, so good, BUT I can't seem to get my form to post.

I have spent a significant amount of time today trying to figure out why it will not post. I guess i'm just not understanding what is wrong with my code, and I hope someone could take a look and point out what is wrong with it, so it goes as follows...

my app.js looks like this...

```
const express = require('express');
      http = require('http');
      path = require('path');
      session = require('express-session');
      app = express();
      mysql      = require('mysql');
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');
      db = require(__dirname, 'models/db')

var index = require('./routes/index');
var register = require('./routes/register');

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/register', register);

var engine = require('ejs-mate');
app.engine('ejs', engine);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


var server = http.createServer(app);

var port = 8995;
server.listen(port);

module.exports = app;
```

my register.js looks like this...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require(__dirname, 'models/db');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Register for a free account' });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
  var today = new Date();
  var users = {
    "first_name":req.body.first_name,
    "last_name":req.body.last_name,
    "email":req.body.email,
    "password":req.body.password,
    "username": req.body.username,
    "created":today,
    "modified":today
  };
  db.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ', users, function(err, result) {
    connection.release();
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    });
  });
  res.redirect('/index');
});
module.exports = router;
```

and lastly, my register.ejs looks like this...

```
<% layout("/layouts/default") -%>
<div class="signup-form">
    <form method="post" action="/register" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Username</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" required="required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="text-center">Already have an account? <a href="/">Login here</a></div>
</div>
```

I don't see why the error CANNOT POST /register comes up when I try to submit my form because i'm specifying what route to post ('/register') in my app.post

Answer (score 1):

You’ve added the register router to be bound to the ‘/register’ link... so all links in route register will have to start with /register/... 
if you try to post /register/register it will work

```
app.use(‘/‘, register)
```

Will work

Comment: Another method would be to change `router.post('/register', ...` to `router.post('/', ...`.

Comment: Great, it works! now i'm getting an error: ` TypeError: db.getConnection is not a function `  is that not how you establish a connection in mysql from your models?

Comment: That should be posted on another question

Comment: my db.js models is as follows.... `var mysql = require('mysql');

var mainDb = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.mysql_host,
  user     : process.env.mysql_user,
  password : process.env.mysql_pwd,
  database : process.env.mysql_db
});

exports.getConnection = function(callback) {
  mainDb.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return;
    }
      callback(err, connection);
  });
};`